# How to Transfer Real BTC From My Wallet to another account using C#

Tags: bitcoin-core, nbitcoin

Hi I wanted to send BTC from my wallet to another wallet through any C# Library. Currently i am using NBitcoin Library to perform this action. But, i am not able to get through it.
Thanks

Comment: Let me know if this helps: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/99534/

Comment: @Prayank
Hi thankyou for the link. I am now able to send my amount. But after i did my first transaction, after that  the transactionId didn't work. Do we need to get latest transactionId after the first transaction.